# django queryset able update own model's field with existing value + 1?

Tags: python, django, model, save, updates

sorry if the title does not make too much sense, I am not sure how to put it in a correct way with only little words.

Anyways, what I really want is...I know we can `filter querysets` then use `update` to update all the fields in the `queryset` without doing a loop then `save()`

But what I really need here is something like......

`User.objects.filter().update(username=this is where I want to update BUT I want to update itself's username+1)`

if I do it in a loopie way, it'll be something like

```
all_users = User.objects.filter()
for user in all_users:
    user.username = user.username + str(1)
    user.save()
```

but is there a way to use `update` and do that?

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Are you actually doing that to avoid duplicate `username`? there's plenty other powerful ways to achieve that

Comment: @Lemayzeur nope I am not doing that for duplicate `username` username is just an example

Answer (score 0):

It's possible to do it with [`F()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/models/expressions/#f-expressions) from `django.db.models`

```
from django.db.models import F
User.objects.filter(pk=pk).update(new_attr=F('username')+str(1))
```

or

```
all_users = User.objects.filter()
for user in all_users:
   user.username =  F('username') + str(1)
   user.save()
```

Comment: weird, I did what you did here..somehow it's saving the field into 2.  I was doing something like `F('username')[:-1]` which should get ride of the last char right? Gives me an error of `not found __getitem`  if I do waht is in your example `F('username') + str(1)` saves 2 into my db though

Comment: How ? it saves 2 records, or it assigns the field a value of `2`?

Comment: assigned value of 2 which is weird, actually I gave it a few tries...instead of giving `str(1)` I tried 'hello` which gave me 2 too O.o